# Nodejs/Phonegap/Cordova no tablet

Tags: node.js, apache-cordova

Eu compartilho o 3G do Celular com o meu tablet android quando estou no ônibus fretado. Aí vem a pergunta:

Eu gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de utilizar o ambiente de desenvolvimento do NodeJs/Phonegap/Cordova para desenvolver no tablet e emular no próprio celular que estou compartilhando o 3G?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem a sua pergunta, mas se todos os seus devices estiverem na mesma rede (no caso conectados na rede 3g do seu telefone) é possível executar o app utilizando o comando `phonegap serve` + o `phonegap app` (você pode baixa-lo na store apple ou google, dependendo do sua plataforma).

[Aqui tem um vídeo mostrando um pouco do phonegap app.](http://www.loiane.com/2015/04/curso-phonegap-cordova-aula-05-testando-com-phonegap-developer-app/) Atente-se apenas às limitações que este recurso oferece.

Não existe a possibilidade de jogar o app para dentro de um device diretamente sem que o mesmo esteja conectado ao outro via cabo e que o dispositivo utilizado para desenvolvimento possua os drivers us do fabricante.

**EDIT**

Montar um ambiente Tablet > Mobile não é algo trivial e creio que não seja possível. Você teria que instalar o NODE no seu device, só isso ai já te complica já que não temos isso disponível (Eu pelo menos não achei nada na internet).

Outro problema são as IDE's cloud que existem (eXo Plaform, codenvi, etc...) Elas podem ajudar um pouco, mas são muito limitadas e creio eu que não vão te atender.

**Opinião MINHA**

Bem, vou deixar destacado que isto é *minha* opinião: Não entendo realmente o motivo de você querer desenvolver em um tablet, já que contam com poucos recursos computacionais e tem interface ruim para trabalhar.

Se você realmente precisa de tanta mobilidade assim recomendo comprar um ultra fino, desenvolver sistemas em telefones, tablets e gadgets e algo *ainda* limitadíssimo a ponto de ser quase impossível.

Comment: Entendi a sua resposta, eu  sei desevolver se o Ambiente de desenvolvimento for CPU -> Mobile  mas ainda nao ficou totalmente claro como posso montar o ambiente TABLET - > Mobile

Comment: Cara, até fiz um edit. Mas não creio que seja possível. Você chegou a conseguir algo?

Answer (score 0):

Como comentado na resposta anterior, a menos que seu Tablet possua Windows ou Linux como sistema operacional dificilmente irá conseguir criar um ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Mas existe uma alternativa, não é a melhor forma, mas pode funcionar.

Você poderia criar uma aplicação bem simples, com intuito de ler os arquivos **HTML/JavaScript/Imagens** do cartão de memoria e não da pasta WWW. Dessa forma sua aplicação principal apenas verificar se em uma pasta da memoria do telefone (ou cartão) existe os arquivos, se sim, tu faz o aplicativo principal executar eles.

Eu sei que isso torna tudo mais complexo, que a aplicação fica com código livre, que tu não vai poder utilizar plugin's externos, que provavelmente terá que solicitar/definir o uso de todas as permissões possíveis do smartphone além de é claro o fato de que debugar a aplicação vai ficar bem mais complexo. Porém se você realmente precisa de algo assim pode adaptar a ideia e desenvolver algo similar.